# How to refresh a ribbon control more often in MS Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word, ribbon

I am writing a *.dotm including vba macros and a custumUI ribbon tab with numerous controls. For some of these controls, the enabled state (computed by a callback specified as `getEnabled` attribute in XML) may change not only by actions under my control (i.e., caused by pushing some of my other buttons), but also by actions not under my control (e.g., user changes the current printer).
Unfortunately, the `getEnabled` is executed only upon startup and if I manually call `refresh` (e.g., as last step of in the action macros called from other controls), but apparently I need refresh to occur also in other situations.

At least all changes I want to defend against involve switching to another tab and back. Hence it would suffice to solve the following problem:

> Is it possible to call a refresh on my ribbon tab each time it gets switched to/becomes visible (again)?

I suspected there might exist an xml attribute `onSelect` or `onShow` or the like that could be added to the controls or the tab, but that does not seem to be the case ...

Comment: Which version of Word are we discussing? 2007 has fewer possibilities than 2010 and later... And no, there's no event (callback) for clicking on a Ribbon Tab. Possibly, something might be done with the Windows API, but that's not something I can help you with. Best I can come up with is to hook into the events Word does provide, such as DocumentBeforePrint (which is likely to trigger if the user is changing the printer) and put a Ribbon.Invalidate in that.

Comment: @CindyMeister Question title says Word 2010, but anything that would also work for 2007 would be welcome. Changing printer was in theory just an example, but in fact up to now the only serious example; this might coer most of my problems ...